# Max 20 Friends Information on Twitter4J

Tags: java, eclipse, api, size, twitter4j

Like you see in this code, I want to get all the information about friends in twitter, people I follow.
But doing this :

```
PagableResponseList<User> users = twitter.getFriendsList(USER_ID, CURSOR);
```

... only gives me the first 20 recent friends... What can I do?

Complete code about it :

```
PagableResponseList<User> users = twitter.getFriendsList(USER_ID, CURSOR);
        User user = null;
        max = users.size();

        System.out.println("Following: "+max);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < users.size() ; i++){

            user = users.get(i);

            System.out.print("\nID: "+user.getId()+" / User: "+user.getName()+" /");
            System.out.print("\nFollowers: "+user.getFollowersCount()+"\n");

            tid.add(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(user.getId())));
            tusername.add(user.getName());
            tfollowers.add(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(user.getFollowersCount())));
            tname.add(user.getScreenName());

        }
```

Thanks..

Comment: by default you'll get only 20 user list and after that cursor will break.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the solution to my post... thanks to **Sander**, give me some ideas...

The thing was change the `for` to `while ((CURSOR = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);`.

And... `user = twitter.showUser(id);`

Playing with showUser makes it possible to  get, with a slowly time, all the info about all my friends...

That's all. Don't use *user.get(i);*

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code to get the list of people you follow.

```
long cursor = -1;
PagableResponseList<User> users;
while ((cursor = followers.getNextCursor()) != 0); 
 {
     users = twitter.getFriendsList(userId, cursor);
 }
```

Comment: Don't works, changin' List for PagableResponseList gives me the restriction of 20 people I follow :/

Comment: i have updated the answer you can try this way now we have change the cursor value and now it will not stop at 20.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a peek at the documentation at Twitter4J and Twitter themselves and it's all about that cursor.

To prevent you're getting loaded with a whole bunch of friends at once, Twitter only returns the first 20 results. It doesn't return just the first 20 results, but it also returns a cursor. That cursor is just a random number that's managed by Twitter. When you make a call again and pass this cursor, the next 20 entries (friends) will be returned, again with a cursor that's different now. You can repeat this until the cursor returned is zero. That means there are no more entries available.

In case you want to know more, check these two links: [Twitter DEV](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring) and [Twitter4J documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#getFriendsList-long-long-).

Concerning your Java, you just need to find a way to get the current cursor, and pass that cursor to your method again, making the app load the next 20 entries. According to [this piece of information](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/PagableResponseList.html), that should do the trick.

```
List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
PagableResponseList<User> users;
long cursor = -1;

while (cursor != 0) {
    users = twitter.getFriendsList(USER_ID, cursor);
    cursor = users.getNextCursor();
    allUsers.add(users);
}
```

Comment: Don't works, Thanks. The rate limit avoids the cursor. I'm thinkin' about work with Paging but there's no way my friend Sanser, there's no way...

Comment: That's strange.. This does seem like it's the right way to do it. I searched a bit further and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618037/twitter-rate-limit-hit-while-requesting-friends-with-ruby-gem

In that post, the rate limit also gets hit after a certain number of friends/followers/whatever. When you look at the mentioned 'working' solution, it works the same way as my solution does, using recursion. (https://gist.github.com/kent/451413)

Comment: How big is that friends list, actually?
If I look at this page (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits), it seems you can make a request 15 times before being limited. Per request, you get 20 friends, so a maximum of 300 friends can be retrieved.

How weird/stupid would it be to actually having to wait until that rate limit is over and query the next x friends, if you have over a 300 friends?

*edit* It seems it is that stupid. Found another person having problems with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174820/rate-limit-twitter-api

Comment: Yes but always I do the request, it will give the same 20 friends, because I start the java program at every request... so..

Comment: This limit is not updated or is not the limit that appears on my console

Comment: Got the solution in an answer.. Thanks to your help really

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to request up to [200 results at a time](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#getFollowersList-long-long-int-):

```
final PagableResponseList<User> users = twitter.getFriendsList(USER_ID, cursor, 200);
cursor = users.getNextCursor();
```

If you need to start from where you left off between invocations of your program then you need to store the value of `cursor` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Improvements to [Sander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26056229/3086097)!

1. You can set a count value to the `getFriendsList` method as in [Jonathan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059575/3086097). The maximum value allowed for count is 200. The loop construct will help to collect more than 200 friends now. 200 friends per page or per iteration!
2. Yet, there are [rate limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits) for any request you make. The `getFriendsList` method will use this api endpoint: `GET friends/list` which has a rate limit of 15 hits per 15 minutes. Each hit can fetch a maximum of 200 friends which equates to a total of 3000 friends *(15 x 200 = 3000)* per 15 minutes. So, there will be no problem if you have only 3000 friends. If you have more than 3000 friends, an exception will be thrown. You can use the `RateLimitStatus` class to avoid that exception. The following code is an example implementation to achieve this.

**Method 1: *fetchFriends(long userId)***

```
public List<User> fetchFriends(long userId) {

    List<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

    PagableResponseList<User> page;
    long cursor = -1;

    try {
        while (cursor != 0) {
            page = twitter.getFriendsList(userId, cursor, 200);
            friends.addAll(page);
            System.out.println("Total number of friends fetched so far: " + friends.size());

            cursor = page.getNextCursor();

            this.handleRateLimit(page.getRateLimitStatus());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return friends;
}
```

**Method 2: *handleRateLimit(RateLimitStatus rls)***

```
private void handleRateLimit(RateLimitStatus rls) {
    int remaining = rls.getRemaining();
    System.out.println("Rate Limit Remaining: " + remaining);
    if (remaining == 0) {
        int resetTime = rls.getSecondsUntilReset() + 5;
        int sleep = (resetTime * 1000);
        try {
            if(sleep > 0) {
                System.out.println("Rate Limit Exceeded. Sleep for " + (sleep / 1000) + " seconds..");
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

By doing so, your program will sleep for some time period based on the rate limiting threshold. It will continue to run from where it left after the sleep. This way we can avoid our program stopping in the midway of collecting friends counting more than 3000.